# Error while trying to setup active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I was trying to setup active admin, and somehow managed to mess up one of the steps.  After running the rails g active_admin:install, I raked the database, then started the rails server.  When I navigate to localhost:3000/admin  I receive the following error.

```
NoMethodError in Active_admin/devise/sessions#new
undefined method `new_password_path' for #<#<Class:0x10347f280>:0x103148210>
Extracted source (around line #10):

7: <% end -%>
8: 
9: <%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' %>
10:   <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
11: <% end -%>
12: 
13: <%- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && controller_name != 'confirmations' %>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or how to completely remove active admin(delete files, undo migrations, undo changes to other files) and start over with a clean slate?  I am using rails 3.0.9.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys, that was the problem.  I'm going to mark the first responder as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise routes must always be created inside your `config/routes.rb` file.

You can add `devise_for :users` or `devise_for :name` for a custom name you create, like admin or moderator...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't add devise to routes. You should add something like:

```
devise_for :users
```